# Saving 40 GB of data to SD Card and losing most of it

Tags: filesystems, data-recovery, restore, sd-card

I have recently used an sdhc card (64GB) to backup computer data. Before formatting, I saved around 40 GB of photos to the card. After formatting, I could only retrieve 7GB of data from the SD Card. The rest of folders are empty. I had formatted it as exFat , so I thought it would not be an issue to store that amount of data.  When I go to properties I see 40GB used, but, in reality there's only 7GB.

What happened with the photos? Is it a problem with the format, or, capacity?  I've tried some recovery software with no success.

Comment: Was it a brand named card from a shop or a cheap one from the internets? There are many people selling cheap 64GB SD cards that are actually broken and only contain a few GBs of working memory. Rest of the stuff comes back as zeroes and if it's in place of a directory, it's broken. If inside a file, there's a bunch of zeroes there. I suggest trying a test program to see if the card is valid.

Comment: Tip for the future: Use actual hard drives for backup. HDDs are super cheap nowadays and an external adapter is a one-time-buy. You can use SSDs if you care about speed, but if you run the backup overnight or smth you might as well get some cheap storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen this quite a bit with cheap china drives. I have probably 100 flash drives that my work bought and were supposed to be 2gb drives with our logo on them. Most only have 128MB useable space. if you write any more than that you might as well consider it lost. I have also seen sd cards that were this way as well.

http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/System-Miscellaneous/H2testw.shtml H2testw is a wonderful program for testing cards before you trust them. It will fill the drive up and then read back off it and see if it gets the same thing back. DO NOT use this if you are gonna try any more recovery software on the drive.

Have you tried the recovery software on the computer as opposed to the sd card? You may have better luck.

Comment: My gosh, I think you're right, I bought it from China. But i was puzzled because a couple days ago i tried to copy 1 folder 5 times, and 5 times the folder was empty. My last chance is to try the recovery software on the computer. thanks.